# Matching character values and changing an according value in a different column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to match character vector `values[1:73]` with a column in a data frame to make changes to a completely different column in the same data frame  (1,258 x 74).

Let say, the vector is

```
 [1] "AA1"                   "BB1"                              
 [3] "AA2"                   "BB2"
```

and the data frame is

```
   Instrument             Holder        
   <chr>                  <chr>                       
 1 CB                     AA1
 2 CH                     BB2
 3 CH                     XX
 4 CB                     YY
 5 CH                     BB2
```

Now I need to match the vector with `df$Holder` and change CH to CB in `df$Instrument` if it matches.

I have tried `match()` and some filtering but end up with the wrong output.

```
indx <- match(vector, df$Holder)
indx <- indx[!is.na(indx)]

for (i in seq_along(indx)) {
  df$Instument[indx[i]] <- c("CB")
}
```

and

```
for (i in seq_along(vector)){
  new <- df %>%
    filter(Holder == vector[i]) %>%
    mutate(Instrument = "CB")
}
```

Look forward to your thoughts!

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by 'matching' vector and df$Holder? what counts as being matched in your situation? Can you specify the desired output so we would be able to know what is a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, but I think this is what you want:

## data

```
vector <- c("AA1", "BB1", "AA2", "BB2")
library(dplyr)
df <- tribble(
~Instrument,           ~Holder,                    
 "CB",                     "AA1",
 "CH",                     "BB2",
 "CH",                     "XX",
 "CB",                     "YY",
 "CH",                     "BB2"  
)
```

## 'matching'

```
df_new <- df %>% 
  mutate(test = stringi::stri_detect_regex(
    df$Holder,
    paste0(vector, collapse = "|")
  )) %>% 
  mutate(Instrument = ifelse(test,
                             "CB",
                             Instrument))
df_new
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   Instrument Holder test 
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <lgl>
#> 1 CB         AA1    TRUE 
#> 2 CB         BB2    TRUE 
#> 3 CH         XX     FALSE
#> 4 CB         YY     FALSE
#> 5 CB         BB2    TRUE
```

For your benefit, I make a new column called test, so it's easier to see what is happening. Whenever `test` is `TRUE`, the column Instrument is changed, otherwise it stays the same. `paste0(vector, collapse = "|")` makes a single regex from the different patterns in your vector. `stringi::stri_detect_regex` bascially does the same as `grepl`namely returning `TRUE` if the pattern was found in the string. (But if you don't want to use `stringi` here is the same with `grepl` `mutate(test = grepl(paste0(vector, collapse = "|"),  df$Holder))`.)

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks!